# How can I customize WCF client code generation?

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl, t4

Are there any tools or code generation templates that will let me customize and extend the WCF cliend proxies? It's not that svcutil is horribly broken, but rather I'd like to be able to generatate additional code based on the service contract, not just be limited the svcutil output.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [Web Service Software Factory](http://www.codeplex.com/servicefactory)? It allows you to have complete control over the generation of proxy code.

Comment: I'm looking now. Looks like a long install and eval process.

Comment: Any chance you could point to docs on how how to the the above to generate clients for existing WCF services?

Comment: You would have create a model for the existing service, probably by hand, as their import tool didn't work well last time I looked. Then just generate the code for the client.

The documentation is oin the codeplex site.

Answer (score 1):

I've since found two other options:

1. [wscf.blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/)
2. [WCF Proxy Genererator](http://wcfproxygenerator.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There are several T4 templates available around the web.  Here are some :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/WCFWrapperUsingT4.aspx
http://staxmanade.blogspot.com/2009/04/t4-replacement-for-add-service.html