# Silverlight + WCF: configure collection type per call?

Tags: c#, arrays, silverlight, wcf

When configuring our service references in Silverlight, there is an option to choose the collection type that is generated for calls that return arrays, like so:

It is an option that you can see when you use the 'configure service reference' context menu item.  I'd upload an image, but I can't do that from work...

I was wondering if there was a way to configure them on a per-call basis, so that I could have an observable collection in some cases, or an array in others?  Is this type of thing possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that out of the box, no, this type of configuration is not possible.  I did stumble across a similar question while doing research on third party tools however.

[How can I customize WCF client code generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035722/how-can-i-customize-wcf-client-code-generation)

Its answer lists a number of different option for generating client code that is custom tailored to your needs.  I haven't tried any of them out though.